# Create New List with Cumulative Sum

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to solve this problem

> Exercise 8.3 Write a function that takes a list of numbers and returns
>   the cumulative sum; that is, a new list where the ith element is the
>   sum of the first i + 1 elements from the original list. For example,
>   the cumulative sum of [1, 2, 3] is [1, 3, 6].

I have written this code which according to me is correct.

```
let lastItem = function 
  | [] -> 0
  | l -> List.hd (List.rev l);;

let rec cumulativeSumActual accum input =
match input with
  | [] -> accum
  | hd::tl -> cumulativeSumActual (accum::[(lastItem accum) + hd]) tl;;

let cumulativeSum = cumulativeSumActual [];;

let output = cumulativeSum [1; 2; 3;];;

let printer item =
    print_int item
    print_string "\n";;

List.iter printer output
```

But I get the error

```
user1@ubuntu:~/Documents/Programs$ ocamlc -o CumulativeList CumulativeList.ml
File "CumulativeList.ml", line 8, characters 33-38:
Error: This expression has type 'a list
       but an expression was expected of type 'a
```

Then I changed my code to

```
  | hd::tl -> cumulativeSumActual (accum@[(lastItem accum) + hd]) tl;;
```

And it worked!

But I don't understand why did the cons operator did not work and why did the new list append operation work?

The cons operator should have simply added a new item to the list and then returned the new list as the first parameter to the recursive call?

What's going on?

Comment: Also, here is a 1 line solution to the problem: `List.scan (+) 0 [1;2;3] |> List.iter (printfn "%i");;`

Comment: I assume `scan` is an F# function, because it is not in the OCaml standard library. After looking up the function, it is not a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this expression:

```
lastItem accum
```

the argument type of `lastItem` is `'a list`.

As a result, `accum` has a type of `'a list`.

The operator `::` requires an element on the left and a list on the right, but you applied it to a list on the left, so you get an error.  The `@` operator allows for a list on either side so it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `con` is to push an element to a list at the head. For example, `12::[13,1,3]`. You can't `con (::)` a list to a list. In your code, obviously, `accum` is `'a list`, not a `'a`. Your code **(accum::[(lastItem accum) + hd])** is trying to `con` two lists, right?

Second, `@` is the `append` which connects two list, that's why your **| hd::tl -> cumulativeSumActual (accum@[(lastItem accum) + hd]) tl;;** is correct.

Third, I would suggest the solution to be

```
let c_sum l =
  let rec sum pre acc = function
    | [] -> acc
    | hd::tl -> let tmp_sum = pre+hd in sum tmp_sum (tmp_sum::acc) tl
  in sum 0 [] l
```

P.S., you have to be careful when you trying to connect two lists as normally this operation will take O(n) because it needs to traversal one list.

Comment: You've got a typo in the last line: `tl` should be `l`